# Xcode 7 iOS 9 - Simulator showing Black Screen with White Apple Logo

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, ios9, xcode7

Does anyone know the fix to why my iOS Simulator is continuously showing a black screen with a white apple logo? I've searched on all sorts of forums, but no one has been able to give a concrete answer yet.

This has started to happen ever since I upgraded to Xcode 7, and I'm unable to run any of my applications on my iOS simulator. No matter how long I wait, it continues to show that screen.

Comment: Did you search Apple's Developer Forum?  [This thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3890) mentions two possible reasons.

Comment: You can check the device's system.log to see what it's doing.  Is data migration taking a long time to complete for some reason?  Take a sysdiagnose and file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Have you got any solution.I am also facing same problem with xcode 7.3

Comment: FWIW, anyone else who encounters this:  after upgrading Xcode, this took a REALLY long time for me - perhaps half an hour (hard to be sure, as I restarted simulator window twice). I also did Simulator/Reset Content and Settings but I don't know if that helped. I think Reset Content, then go away for half an hour to see if it finally finishes.

Comment: I had copied the the Xcode from my other mac and it was showing black screen, apparently I had copied it to downloads folder, moving it to Applications folder fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings...

Doing that fixed it for me.